# Class translator does not exist when using app()->setLocale() in app service provider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to use localization in my Laravel 5.8 application. Following up with this [How To Build An Efficient and SEO Friendly Multilingual Architecture For Your Laravel Application](https://mydnic.be/post/how-to-build-an-efficient-and-seo-friendly-multilingual-architecture-for-your-laravel-application) I have always do the same steps and have no problems. However, when I try it with Laravel 5.8 I keep getting Class translator does not exist from  `app()->setLocale(request()->segment(1));` I use that in the app service provider for some reason.

**AppServiceProvider**

```
<!-- language: php -->

public function register()
{
    app()->setLocale(request()->segment(1));

    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code from your `AppServiceProvider`?

Comment: @nakov sure i added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `register` method is not to be used for using services.

Try adding your code in the `boot` method of the class.

Also I believe a better place for adding this is in a middleware then in the service provider.

Comment: One question is this new because in older laravel versions i used it in the register method and had no problems?

Comment: No it is not new. The `register` method is used for binding, and there is no guarantee on which provider will be bound first. That's why it might work sometimes, but there is no guarantee that it will work each time, depending on which provider was bound first. The boot method is used for actually using providers as the boot method is called after everything has been bound.